# How can I exclude another value from a column in joined table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I thought this would be a straightforward query to write, but it's proving to be much trickier to achieve than I first thought.

Any help would be much appreciated - it's driving me up the wall :)

I have two tables, one USERS the second; PURCHASED PRODUCTS. A user can have multiple products in the PRODUCTS table.

I have a joined query where I return a list of users that have a specific product - so far so good.

Now here's the problem:

I want to exclude USERS that have another specific product.

Therefore, only return users that have product 1001, NOT users that have both products 1001 AND 1002 in the PRODUCTS table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach:

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u
JOIN purchased_products p
  ON u.user_id = p.user_id AND 
     p.product_id in (1001, 1002)
GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) = 1 AND
       MIN(p.product_id) = 1001
```

Comment: This solution also works as expected and performs well in SQL server. I would say this is the correct solution if performance is a priority. Many thanks Mark.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.*
    FROM users u
        INNER JOIN purchased_products p
            ON u.user_id = p.user_id
                AND p.product_id = 1001
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                         FROM purchased_products p2
                         WHERE p2.product_id = 1002
                             AND p2.user_id = u.user_id)
```

Comment: This works with expected results but is slow. The tables I'm querying are quite large with the users table in excess of 800K rows and the Product table approx. 300K. However, performance isn't critical in this case as I only need to run for occasional reporting. Many thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from `user` 
    LEFT JOIN `product` on `user`.`id` = `product`.`user_id`
    WHERE `product`.`id` = <w1st_product_id>
        AND `user`.`id` NOT IN ( 
           SELECT user_id 
           FROM product 
           WHERE product.id = <2nd_product_id> 
        )
```

Comment: Backticks are MySQL-specific - the OP is using SQLServer.

Comment: This solution also works in SQL server - once backticks removed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from user U
where (select count(*) from product P where P.user_id=U.user_id)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

> only return users that have product 1001, NOT users that have both products 1001 AND 1002 in the PRODUCTS table.

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use

```
SELECT U.Id
FROM [User] U INNER JOIN Product P ON U.Id = P.UserId AND P.ProductId = 1001
EXCEPT
SELECT U.Id
FROM [User] U INNER JOIN Product P ON U.Id = P.UserId AND P.ProductId = 1002
```

which, as the word "`EXCEPT`" suggests, will return the ids for users that have product 1002, except if they also have product 1002.

Comment: In this instance we're using 2000. But you answer is very useful to know, thanks.